# Regular expression to character being repeated more than 1 times

Tags: python, regex

I have dataframe with column 'code':

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['10SGD01AA103||||||10SGD01AA105||||||10SGD01AA111']})
```

How can I drop repeated character '|' and leave only one.

> 10SGD01AA103|10SGD01AA105|10SGD01AA111

I use [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
df['code'] = df['code'].str.replace('|(?=|\1+)', '', regex=True)
```

or

```
df['code'] = df['code'].str.replace('|(?=|)', '', regex=True)
```

But repeated character does not drop.

Comment: Please post code, **data**, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: You need to escape `|` in a regexp.

Comment: `replace(r'\|{2,}', '|', regex=True)`

Comment: This is a just a regex question in disguise. Nothing pandas-specific, other than using `df['code'].str.replace()` accessor to access the regex method on the string column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df["code"] = df["code"].str.replace(r'\|+', '|')
```